# git diff displaying wrong file mode - instead of 775 displaying 755

Tags: linux, git

I have recenlty changed system and few files started appearing in git diff. Its due to mode change and am ok  with that for now.

I am wondering why git diff displaying mode 755, when it supposed to 775. In below screen all linux command says it is 775, but git diff says  it is 755.

OS is Ubuntu 22.04.

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git only stores one bit (as in binary digit) of "mode" information per ordinary file: "executable" (`+x`) or "not executable" (`-x`).  This single bit of mode information is, however, stored as `mode 100755` (`+x`) or `mode 100644` (`-x`).

It's no coincidence that `100755` corresponds to a Linux `0755` file mode: in fact, the `100` part is from `S_IFREG` in `<sys/stat.h>`.  Likewise `100644` corresponds to a file whose mode is `0644` or `rw-r--r--`.  *In the distant past, Git did store more mode bits per file*.  But this was discovered to be a mistake, so now Git stores only the one mode bit—but uses the same *encoding* it used back when it stored more bits.

The actual file permission bits that you'll find on disk will depend on your `umask` setting, not on the `mode 100755` setting.  If you have `umask 022`, Git will create executable files with mode 0755 or `rwxr-xr-x`.  If you change your umask to `002`, Git will create such files with mode 0775 or `rwxrwxr-x`.  But the old and/or new `mode` as shown in `git diff` output will always be either `100644` or `100755`, and that means `-x` or `+x` respectively.

Comment: so what I understand git will treat these 4 permissions similar 1) -x--x--x 2) --x-----x, 3) -----x--x, 4) --------- because stores only single bit, and this single bit storage is depends on 0002 or 0022. Is that correct ? to keep it single I didn't included rw part.

Comment: Mostly right (the last one has no `x` bit): on Linux-y systems, Git does an `lstat` on the file and looks to see if any `x` bit is set, choosing the mode from that: `e->mode = (stat_result.st_mode & 0111) ? 100755 : 100644`, more or less.

Comment: On systems where the `st_mode` field is unreliable, Git sets `core.filemode` to `false` at repository creation time. Here, instead of looking at the `lstat` `st_mode` field, Git looks at the *existing index entry's mode* to determine the new index entry mode. To change the mode after `git add`, use `git update-index --chmod=` with `+x` or `-x`. Note that `core.filemode` is set *only once*, during creation of the repository, based on the OS's observed behavior. This is because you can mount an MS-DOS FAT file system on a Linux system, for instance.

Comment: Git assumes that the repository lives in a file system whose behavior never changes. To move a repository from one file system to another, Git assumes you will use `git clone` to create a new repository; the creation tests the behavior and sets the `core.filemode` variable in the new repository. (`core.ignoreCase` behaves the same way. There should perhaps be a porcelain Git command to "re-test" the behavior of stat, case-sensitivity, and the like, but the need is minuscule and Git has never acquired one.)

Comment: thanks a ton for spending  time and explaining in such a detail.

Answer (score 1):

When storing a file (blob) in Git, there are only two possible file modes: 644 or 755.  That is, Git stores only the executable bit, and if it is set, it stores the latter, and if not, it stores the former.  Thus, for diffs, Git will only reflect whether the executable bit is set and will always use one of those two modes.

In the working tree, Git uses the umask to set permissions, which explains why your files are actually 775.